# Gentle way for removing named variable from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there possibility to write function `f()`, which I can use for subsetting columns set which we can use strictly like this : `data[, f(c("var1", "var2", "var3"))]` without using `data` as argument,`f()` could be something like :

```
f <- function(data_frame, minus_colnames)
     return colnames(data_frame)[which(!colnames(data_frame)%in%minus_colnames)]
```

but can we somehow call `f` without explicitly pointing to `data` dataframe like :

`data[, f(c("var1", "var2", "var3"))]`

not like

`data[, f(data, c("var1", "var2", "var3"))]` (and without `dplyr`) ?

That would be most suitable syntax for me

Comment: Also probably using `setdiff(names(data), c("var1", "var2", "var3"))`

Comment: I should have realized there would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
subset(data, select= -c(var1, var2, var3))
```

or

```
data[,!names(data) %in% c("var1","var2","var3"))]
```

or as @DavidArenburg suggests

```
setdiff(names(data), c("var1", "var2", "var3")
```

`dplyr::select` is another option; I'm sure there are `data.table` solutions too.

Comment: The dplyr option could be `select(data, -num_range("var", 1:3))`, for example. (+1)

Comment: To finish it off `dt[, !paste0('var', 1:3), with=F]` and `dt[, paste0('var', 1:3) := NULL]` for data.table